# request.user not available in Streamblocks subtemplate

Tags: django, wagtail

In my main template I can call:

```
{% load static wagtailuserbar wagtailcore_tags %}
{% load navigation_tags %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
You're logged in
{% endif %}
```

but if I call this in my StreamBlock sub-template, it doesn't work.

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="container">
...
</div>
{% endif %}

Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When outputting the StreamField onto the page, be sure to use the [include_block](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering) tag rather than just outputting the value within a `{{ ... }}` tag. This ensures that any variables defined on the outer template, including `request`, are passed on to the sub-template. If you use `{{ ... }}`, the sub-template will still be rendered, but the only available variables are the ones supplied by the block itself.

`{% include_block %}` can be used on an individual block, or the stream as a whole:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% include_block page.body %}

or

{% for block in page.body %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```

You'll also need to do this within any sub-templates that render sub-sub-templates (for example, if you have a nested StreamBlock within the StreamField, the template for that StreamBlock needs to use `include_block` too).